# How can I serve my static files with Node/express?

Tags: express, directory

I have a Node.js backend, using express.js as my middleware.  My backend code:

```
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'angular-src/src/assets'));
```

My folder structure:

```
/ProjectName
 angular-src
   |__ src
      |__ app
      |__ assets
          |__ css
              |__ style.css
          |__ fonts
          |__ images
              |__ auth
                 |__ login_1.jpg
 app.js
```

In style.css file, it is using:

```
background-image: url("../images/auth/login_1.jpg");
```

I'm receiving a 404 error for this login_1.jpg file which I believe means that my static files aren't being served.  Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the URL in the web page to start with `/`:

```
background-image: url("/images/auth/login_1.jpg");
```

You don't want the URL to be relative to the path of the page which the browser assumes it to be when you start it with `..`.  Instead, you want it to start with `/` so that the browser won't mess with the path and will just request that path directly from your server.  Then `express.static()` will use this path `/ProjectName/angular-src/src/assets` as the parent and then append onto it the requested path to look for a matching file.

Also, this assumes that `__dirname` as used in `path.join(__dirname, 'angular-src/src/assets')` is `/ProjectName`.  If that's not the case, then you need to fix the stop part of the path you're sending to `express.static()`.

---

Keep in mind that when you do this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'angular-src/src/assets'));
```

You're telling express that you want it to use that particular directory as a root and for any URL that is requested by the browser, Express should look for a matching file starting at that root.  So, if the browser requests `/hello.html`, then Express should look in that static directory for a file named `hello.html` and if found serve it.  If the browser requests `/images/auth/login_1.jpg`, then Express should take that above root and append `/images/auth/login_1.jpg` onto it and see if that file exists.  If so, serve it.

Remember also that the browser will always request absolute paths.  So, if you put a relative link in the HTML page, then the browser will combine the path from the current web page URL to make an absolute URL.

---

You can also use the network tab in the Chrome debugger at any time to see what exact URL the browser is requesting.  If you want to see that same info on the server, you can insert this pass-thru middleware as one of your first routes (before the `express.static()` middleware):

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.originalUrl);
    next();
});
```

Comment: Holy smokes it worked.  You also provided an 'education' on the matter of serving static files so for that I gladly thank you.  Every doc/tutorial I came across just had a simple '/public' folder at the root which didn't provide much 'under the hood' explanation for why the function was operating the way it was.